# Update DataGrid bound to DataTable after DataTable is altered WPF

Tags: mysql, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a combobox where the user can select a particular year (populated by the database) and view particular information for the year. That information is stored in a datatable which is bound to a datagrid. I want it to recreate the data grid when I change the year.
 `_PropertyTenantData` is a DataTable that has 14 columns Property Id, Property and year + Month. FillDataGrid creates the columns of `_PropertyTenantData` with a given year, and runs a MySQL query which fills its rows. When the selection in the ComboBox changes I want to refresh the DataGrid because it will have new column names and different data.

```
public ViewCurrentPropertyTenant : Window
{
    FillComboBox();
    FillDataGrid("2010");
    InitializeComponent();
}

//...

private void cboYear_SelectionChangd(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
{ 
    object selectedItem = cboYear.SelectedItem;
    string year = (selectedItem as YearData).Year;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
    {
        _PropertyTenantData.Reset();
        FillDataGrid(year);
        myGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The first part runs fine and gives me the data as I want it structured. The second part removes all the rows, the columns stay the same, and the new rows of `_PropertyTenantData` are not added to the dataGrid. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. Instead of refreshing I just did this:

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = _PropertyTenantData.DefaultView;
```